# Python datetime.strptime() Eating lots of CPU Time

Tags: python, optimization, datetime

I have some log parsing code that needs to turn a timestamp into a datetime object. I am using datetime.strptime but this function is using a lot of cputime according to cProfile's cumtime column. The timestamps are in the format of `01/Nov/2010:07:49:33`.

The current function is:

```
new_entry['time'] = datetime.strptime(
        parsed_line['day'] +
        parsed_line['month'] +
        parsed_line['year'] +
        parsed_line['hour'] +
        parsed_line['minute'] +
        parsed_line['second']
        , "%d%b%Y%H%M%S"
)
```

Anyone know how I might optimize this?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

If those are fixed width formats then there is no need to parse the line - you can use slicing and a dictionary lookup to get the fields directly.

```
month_abbreviations = {'Jan': 1, 'Feb': 2, 'Mar': 3, 'Apr': 4,
                       'May': 5, 'Jun': 6, 'Jul': 7, 'Aug': 8,
                       'Sep': 9, 'Oct': 10, 'Nov': 11, 'Dec': 12}
year = int(line[7:11])
month = month_abbreviations[line[3:6]]
day = int(line[0:2])
hour = int(line[12:14])
minute = int(line[15:17])
second = int(line[18:20])
new_entry['time'] = datetime.datetime(year, month, day, hour, minute, second)
```

Testing in the manner shown by [Glenn Maynard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4070900/python-datetime-strptime-eating-lots-of-cpu-time/4071317#4071317) shows this to be about 3 times faster.

Comment: Made this into a function and tested it in my code against the same 1 million log lines several times going back and forth between this and strptime(). Total Parse time consistently when down from 80 to 50 seconds!

Comment: Good solution. Could you please also suggest what can I do if I have 12 hour format for hours. Is there any other way to handle that besides putting conditions and doing it manually?

Comment: @Naman you could add `am_pm_offset={'AM':0,'PM':12}` and add that to the hours.

Comment: @MarkRansom Sorry for getting back on this so late but adding the offset doesn't work. Since 12:45 P.M. is valid time but offset added 24:45 is not. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/12-hour_clock . Any other fast method? I don't wanna put conditions

Comment: @Naman you're absolutely right, sorry I didn't think of that myself. You can use modular arithmetic to fix it: `hour = int(line[12:14]) % 12 + am_pm_offset[??]`

Comment: Thanks. This works perfectly and surprisingly a little faster than if condition checking.

Answer (score 3):

It seems that using strptime() on a Windows platform uses a Python implementation (_strptime.py in the Lib directory). and not a C one.  It might be quicker to process the string yourself.

```
from datetime import datetime
import timeit

def f():
    datetime.strptime ("2010-11-01", "%Y-%m-%d")

n = 100000
print "%.6f" % (timeit.timeit(f, number=n)/n)
```

returns 0.000049 on my system, whereas

```
from datetime import date
import timeit

def f():
    parts = [int (x) for x in "2010-11-01".split ("-")]
    return date (parts[0], parts[1], parts[2])    

n = 100000
print "%.6f" % (timeit.timeit(f, number=n)/n)
```

returns 0.000009

Answer (score 2):

**Most recent answer:** if moving to a straight `strptime()` has not improved the running time, then my suspicion is that there is actually no problem here: you have simply written a program, one of whose main purposes in life is to call `strptime()` very many times, and you have written it well enough — with so little other stuff that it does — that the `strptime()` calls are quite properly being allowed to dominate the runtime. I think you could count this as a success rather than a failure, unless you find that (a) some Unicode or LANG setting is making `strptime()` do extra work, or (b) you are calling it more often than you need to. Try, of course, to call it only once for each date to be parsed. :-)

**Follow-up answer after seeing example date string:** Wait! Hold on!  Why are you parsing the line instead of just using a formatting string like:

```
"%d/%b/%Y:%H:%M:%S"
```

**Original off-the-cuff-answer**: If the month were a integer you could do something like this:

```
new_entry['time'] = datetime.datetime(
    int(parsed_line['year']),
    int(parsed_line['month']),
    int(parsed_line['day']),
    int(parsed_line['hour']),
    int(parsed_line['minute']),
    int(parsed_line['second'])
)
```

and avoid creating a big string just to make `strptime()` split it back apart again.  I wonder if there is a way to access the month-name logic directly to do that one textual conversion?

Comment: Tried not parsing apart the date and letting strptime do it as per your edit. didn't make much of a difference in running time...

Comment: When using strptime(), you should just us a formatting string. That's the intended use.

Comment: Well I tried putting that part as its own set of worker threads to speed it up. I got the results I bet most non-threading masters get when they attempt this ... twice as slow ;-)

Comment: The `striptime()` call is typically such a blazingly fast and simple call that absolutely any overhead that you add to it will just slow things down, which is why I did not suggest anything like caching in case there are duplicate dates. I mean, after all, it is written in C rather than Python. And threading was slower, by the way, because standard C Python is not thread-safe and so only one thread at a time can run Python code (though many threads can safely wait on I/O).

Answer (score 2):

What's a "lot of time"?  `strptime` is taking about 30 microseconds here:

```
from datetime import datetime
import timeit
def f():
    datetime.strptime("01/Nov/2010:07:49:33", "%d/%b/%Y:%H:%M:%S")
n = 100000
print "%.6f" % (timeit.timeit(f, number=n)/n)
```

prints 0.000031.

Comment: According to cprofile the cumulative for strptime is 38 CPU seconds.  The total for the program is 154 CPU seconds.

Comment: What? (and the rest of this comment is here because StackOverflow treats its users like children who need forced minimum comment lengths)

Comment: He's parsing a log file and strptime is taking 38s of the total 154s of execution time.